# warning feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, error-handling

My error logs are getting out of control with the two below errors

```
warning feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

and

```
warning fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

The bit of code responsible is

```
<?php
    $file = '../upload/files/' . $filex;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fread($fp, 65536);
        flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

I used this code for header downloads but its freaking out right now - before anyone asks what I have tried, I tried google but still don't fully understand the error message.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work for something the server can handle without PHP at all.

Comment: [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) returns `FALSE` on error.

Comment: It means the file pointer couldn't access the file. Make sure the file is in that location and that the user that the script runs as has read permissions on it. I don't see $filex being assigned anywhere, so make sure it is assigned.

Comment: @NullUserException: Not if the files are outside the webroot.

Comment: A related pointer would be: _if_ you are trying to serve files outside of your document root, [try X-Sendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Comment: $filex is declared at the top of the doc (not on example) and the file download does work so it seems odd it would trigger this. I could understand if the file didnt download.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fopen fails and returns false.
false is not a resource, thus the warning.

You'd better test $fp before injecting it as a resource-like argument:

```
if(($fp = fopen($file, "r"))) {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Went with the top one - makes sense

Comment: I think the second example might end up with infinite loop. Because 
`!@feof(false)` is `true`. I did a simple test with PHP 5.6.4.

Comment: That's right. feof(false) triggers an error but @feof(false) returns false instead. Post edited. Thanks for the warning !

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem. The code ran perfectly on my local environment. But when it was loaded to the server, I got the message discussed in this thread. At the end, the problem was that the server is case-sensitive on file names, while my local environment is not. After having corrected the file name, everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP 7, you can now use the far more efficient method: -

```
$fileRecs = 0;
$file = new SplFileObject('textfile.txt, 'r');
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
$fileRecs = $File->key() + 1;

echo "fileRecs=".$fileRecs;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php