# fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: warnings, fread

I have a PHP Warning.

```
fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /tmp/func.php on line 12
```

My code :

```
<?php

  $sqlite = 'teleinfo.sqlite';

  function getTeleinfo () {

    $handle = fopen ('/dev/ttyACM0', "r"); // ouverture du flux

    while (fread($handle, 1) != chr(2));
--------
```

Thank you !

php --version
PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2015 23:22:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552484/warning-feof-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)

Answer (score 0):

'Boolean given' suggests the return value from your fopen is the value false, so your attempt to open /dev/ttyACM0 for reading failed.
You should check to see if your handle is valid after the fopen before trying to use it

```
$handle = fopen ('/dev/ttyACM0', "r"); // ouverture du flux
if ($handle) {
    while (fread($handle, 1) != chr(2));
    ...
}
```

### As for why? Perhaps the location doesn't exist or you do not have permission or maybe something else has it open with an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 0):

If your are following this tutorial : http://www.magdiblog.fr/gpio/teleinfo-edf-suivi-conso-de-votre-compteur-electrique/

Data is recivied on /dev/ttyAMA0

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 1200 sane evenp parenb cs7 -crtscts
```

But in php script is parsed on /dev/ttyACM0

You should change the filename in php script !