# feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting thousands of error logs that look like this:

```
$xml = "<requisicao-boleto>
                <website>
                    <n_website>{$n_website}</n_website>
                    <password>{$password}</password>
                </website>

                <sacado>
                    <name>{$name}</name>
                    {$user_code}
                    <address>
                        <street>{$street}</street>
                        <complement>{$complement}</complement>
                        <number>{$number}</number>
                        <district>{$district}</district>
                        <state_province>{$state_province}</state_province>
                        <city>{$city}</city>
                        <postcode>{$postcode}</postcode>
                        <country>{$country}</country>
                    </address>
                </sacado>
                <dados_boleto>
                    <product>{$product}</product>
                    <reference>{$uid}</reference>
                    <value>{$value}</value>
                </dados_boleto>
            </requisicao-boleto>";

    $xml = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $xml);
    $xml = "xml=" . $xml;

    $n = strlen($xml);

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => "User-Agent: My Own Http Client\r\n" .
                "Content-length: " . $n . "\r\n",
            'content' => $xml
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $handle = fopen($URL, 'r', false, $context);

    $conteudo = '';

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $conteudo .= fread($handle, 1024);
    }
```

The code is:

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $conteudo .= fread($handle, 1024);
}
```

Has anyone been through a simillar problem and know how to overcome this issue?

I have updated this question with the full code while I try to implement th sugestions that have already been given.

Comment: what does $handel have?

Comment: $handle = fopen($URL, 'r', false, $context);
@ChetanAmeta

Comment: So your fopen() has failed

Comment: And what is in `$context`? Apparently an error occurend when opening the url (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552484/warning-feof-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the fopen worked?

```
$handle = fopen($URL, 'r', false, $context);
if ( $handle === FALSE ) {
    echo 'Cannot open this url ' . $URL;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

I think in your case `fopen` returned `false` and `feof` also returns false. This is why you get infinite loop.

Below is the quote from [`feof`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) documentation

> Returns TRUE if the file pointer is at EOF or an error occurs (including socket timeout); otherwise returns FALSE.

Your example looks like this

```
php > var_dump(feof(false));
PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. feof() php shell code:1
bool(false)
php >
```

You need to check if `$handle` is a resource before doing anything else.